# "No value given for one or more required parameters" Accessing Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, oledb

its my first time to access and read an excel file (xlsx) with c#..
i am having problem and the error was: No value given for one or more required parameters

below is my code:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Class Schedules.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;""";
        string ExcelQuery;
        ExcelQuery = "SELECT A1 FROM [Sheet1$]"; 
        OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        ExcelConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(ExcelQuery, ExcelConnection);
        OleDbDataReader ExcelReader;
        ExcelReader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader(); //error happens here

        while (ExcelReader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show((ExcelReader.GetValue(0)).ToString());
        }
        ExcelConnection.Close();
    }
```

since this is my first time, im just trying to read the content of A1, below is my excel file:

[image]

but running the code would give me an error: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: I just guess... The sheet parameter is not correct.

Comment: should i put Sheet1$ or just Sheet1? coz my reference says it should be Sheet1$

Comment: Try without the `$` sign and see for yourself.

Comment: tried without $ but it gives me another error:
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Comment: It is definitely supposed to include the "$" sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i found a way to read a specific cell in c#....

location `rCnt=1,cCnt=1` is `A1` in excel

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string str;
        int rCnt = 1;  // this is where you put the cell row number
        int cCnt = 1;   // this is where you put the cell column number

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Class Schedules.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;


        str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2; //you now have the value of A1.



        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

be sure to have:

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and add a reference into the project called Microsoft Excel Object Library which can be found under the COM tab...
if you want to read multiple texts, just use for loop
and increment value of rCnt or cCnt...
if you want to write into the cell, i think it could be done this way:

```
(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2 = value;
```

that's all...hope this will help others

Answer (score 0):

From looking in some old code I have, the syntax should be:

```
ExcelQuery = "SELECT * FROM A1:Q10000";
```

Meaning you don't have to specify the sheet name, it will always take from the first or default sheet and you have to specify the range of columns you select as well.

Comment: i already fixed the problem with your solution or just using Sheet1$, but now im having a new problem..error is : could not find installable ISAM

Comment: ok i changed my code again and receive No value given for one or more required parameters error again

Comment: Try using more simple connection string: `string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Class Schedules.xlsx;";` - any luck?

Comment: it says unrecognized data format "C:\Class Schedules.xlsx" when i do that

Comment: Hmm.. what line causes the "could not find installable ISAM" error?

Comment: ExcelReader = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader();
but i have a feeling it cant recognized A1..it cant read that specific cell i think... because when i tried SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
it read the contents of the whole cells..it cant read a specific cell

Comment: So why not just having `SELECT *`? You can access the specific columns by index like you're already doing anyway in your code.

Comment: i think it will not end, i mean excel file has a lot of cells right? it will lag the system

Answer (score 0):

I believe the A1 in your query is the problem. To test just try the following and see it eliminates the error...

```cs
ExcelQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
```

If you want to select specific columns then use HDR=YES instead (in your conn string).

```
string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Class Schedules.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";
```

This signals that the first row of your sheet contains the column names. So it requires your sheet in question be formatted this way but then you can select specific columns...

```
ExcelQuery = "SELECT [Time] FROM [Sheet1$]";
```